# How to stop AVPlayer after did Fast Forward in ios app?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Hi in my application i am launching AVPlayerViewController and while playing content i will fast forward the player after fast forward it will take sometime to start play before it start play again i will close the player.In this scenario i can able to hear audio even after close player.How to resolve this issue please let me know.

I am making player nil and setRate to zero when closing the player.

@try {

```
    [self.player.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
    [self.player.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty"];

    [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
    [self.player setRate:0.0];
    self.player=nil;



} @catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"Execption is %@",exception);
}
```

Player audio should stop when ever we close player. Thanks in advance.